# TCP NewJersey displayed RTT incorrect

Tags: ns2

I am doing a comparison between TCP Protocols over Satellites in NS2. To get the RTT (Round Trip Time) with TCP Jersey, I call something like that

```
proc finish {} {
 global tcp
set rtt [$tcp set rtt_]
}
```

where $tcp is the Agent attached to my node.
The value returned is 16ms whereas it should be of the order of ~150ms. On the tracefile I do have the correct value (156ms) but for plotting reasons and to save processing time, it would be easier to get the correct RTT value without analyzing my tracefile (few millions lines). 
I could not find in my tcp-nj.cc (taken from https://web.njit.edu/anl/download.html) what could cause this. Also note that it works correctly with other imported TCP protocols like Westwood+.

Any clue what could cause this/where to investigate?

PS: Let me know if I need to include more code (my files are quite large and I included the only part dealing with the rtt)